Ground to Phase potential in a ungrounded tri-phase network
I would like to know the possible potential difference between a phase and the earth of an ungrounded three-phase network (intermediate network of figure below).
I can't find out if there's a relationship between the value of the phase-to-earth voltage at the primary (U3g,a U3g,a) and the value at the secondary (U3g,b).
Ideally, I'd like to be able to increase the value of U3g,b.
I'm a bit stuck for a solution.


So the line between TR1 and TR2 in your sketch can be a delta or an ungrounded wye. In any case, better look at the vectors. Assuming it's an ungrounded Y:

In the case of the picture, the voltage between neutral and ground is higher than the phase voltage. It is typical on today's solar photovoltaic generators and happens due to the DC potential of the solar panels.
However, in typical power systems, even if the neutral in ungrounded, the potential between them isn't too different. In fact, in such cases, the system is grounded through stray capacitances that tends to be similar between phases, but not identical, so the neutral fluctuates a bit.
During a short-circuit, one of the phases (or more than one) can touch the ground and in such case the other phases will present the biggest difference to ground.
Hope it helps.

I think you are saying that their is a DC component in the output of the inverters.  Correct?  Do you happen to have a waveform capture showing?  Just curious - and thank you.

Those are phase-to-ground (blue) and phase-to-phase (red) waveshape: https://prnt.sc/UqdipNwmpQ9P

wow, that is a serious DC offset.  Thank you. Is that from simulation or captured?

To be honest, I don't remember exactly. But if itsn't from measurements, it's comming from accurate simulations.

Ok, so according to you, it is possible to get an upper value of this DC component. Do you think it can be calculated theoretically?

In case of a short-circuit between one phase and the ground, The short circuit current would be equal to 0A or some current would flow ?

In ungrounded systems, the phase-to-ground current is 0 "idally". In practice, there is some current which isn't easy to detect. Another effect is the voltage escalation (you will find a bit about it if you google it). I heard from equipment capable of, however, its performance depends on the stray capacitances of the system.

Here some papers answering this question : 
-Transient Overvoltages due to Intermittent-Ground Faults in an Industrial Power System Grounded by a Resistance connected to the Secondary of a Grounding Transformer 
-Transient Overvoltages on Ungrounded Systems from Intermittent Ground Faults

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
